# I can't open a link in a new page in my jquery mmenu.js

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I'm working with jQuery Mobile for make a Mobile App, and I'm using the [JQuery mmenu.js plugin](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) . I'm trying to open in a new window one of the items (link) of mi list, but I can't.

Here is my code:

My Menu:

```
<nav id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="paginas/buscar.php">Buscar</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/FB_PAGE" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
  <li><a href="paginas/creditos.php">Créditos</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

My JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $('#menu').mmenu({
   position: "left"
  });
});
</script>
```

And my menu button

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
  <a href="#menu">Menu</a>
  <h1>Hoy</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: Tell us what happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: Add `data-rel=external` to the button. And/Or `data-ajax=false`.

Comment: @putvande there is no an error. Open the link but in the same page.

Comment: @Omar Thanks but, I tried adding the `data-rel=external`and `data-ajax=false`but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the mmenu-plugin. It assumes your menu is linking to internal pages only. I guess you could prevent this by binding an onClick handler BEFORE firing the plugin that stops the immediate propagation:

```
$('#menu a[target="_blank"]').click(function( e ) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
$('#menu').mmenu();
```

EDIT: bug is fixed in the latest version of the mmenu-plugin (3.0.5) for target="_blank".

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already update my plugin and everything is fixed! Now I can open my links in a new page with a simple `<a href="url" target="_blank">` Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to open the link in the same tab / page?

Comment: @T.BrianJones if you want open the link in the same page just do this: `<a href="[URL]">Buscar</a>` without `target`